# Find First and Last non empty cells move the range to top

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a requirement where the i need to import the xml document to excel file and rearange it below one example on how the file looks like after import, where the data is available from column A to F.

*After Import*

[image: After Import]

Now i have a set of predefined columns and i need to move the set based on the blank cells in the first column.

In the above example column B to E is grouped, and column B's first non empty cell starts on the row 4.  Then i need to find the last non empty cell in Column B, here it is B10.
Now i need to move all data from the range B4 to E10 to the top.  as below image

*Final output*

[image: Final output]

I tried to find the first non empty and last non empty cells.  But not sure how to get the range of cells selected and move to the first available one.  Can you someone help me on this please?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Loop through columns. Starting in each column at the first row, check if empty. If so, delete cell and shift up. Check again, until it's no longer empty. Move to next column.  What have you tried so far? Please share your code and any errors and where they occur.

Comment: Is there XML file to go with this and a vba script we can use to reproduce the problem please? Or do you only care about fixing the problem after the import?

Comment: What about that space above cell `F2`? Is that supposed to be shifted upwards as well?

Comment: look at `range.offset`

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. the XML is bit complex, so as of now am pretty much fine with working within the excel as exporting the XML is not going to take more time for me. @QHarr

Comment: Regarding F2, yes it will be in the next group of column so it might also needs to be shifted. My aim is if i can shift the first group (here B to E) then i can use the same for other groups... i have almost 20 similar groups @dwirony

Comment: @BruceWayne i was building the code, and till now i managed to identify the first used and last used cell, so that i can pass the cell range as the input while moving.  I thought about searching each cell... but i felt it might reduce the performance as my files will be huge sometimes...  thats why i thought about the approach of moving as a range

Comment: @Ibo let me try that and update here...

Comment: Are there ever gaps in Column B? What if, in your example, *before moving anything*, `B4` is `Yellow`, `B5` is empty and then `B6` is `Orange`. Do you want to remove that empty cell too? Or literally get the first, and last cells only, and go from there

Comment: @Bharani How is the macro supposed to know that column F is part of the next group of columns? How should it know that it isn't column E? Without any real pattern you're not going to have an easy time making this **dynamic**.

Comment: @dwirony yea thats right... but i got the grouping chart, so i know the start and end of the groups.  I used BruceWayne's solution with few modifications like used that code as a function and passed the value for start and end columns based on the conditions and it worked as expected...

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `firstRow` and `lastRow` variable, create the range, then cut/move to `B1`:

```
Sub moveGroup()
Dim rng As Range
Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
With Columns("B")
    If .Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then  ' Remember Cells(1,1) is RELATIVE to the range "Column B"
        firstRow = 1
    Else
        firstRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    End If
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "First row is: " & firstRow & "; Last row is: " & lastRow
End With

Set rng = Range("B" & firstRow & ":E" & lastRow)
rng.Cut Destination:=Range("B1")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
With Range("B:E")
    .Resize(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Rows(1).Row - 1).Delete xlShiftUp
End With
```